# Jpeg2000 or webp images with CE IMAGE?

Tags: ce-image

Is it possible to use next-gen formats with CE Image, using Expression Engine 2.8?
What's the alternative?

Answer (score 1):

CE-Image is pretty old now, and I'm also fairly sure it doesn't support outputing images in either webp or Jpeg2000 formats.  Neither does any version of EE.

In theory CE-Image (or some equivalent) could *output* images in those formats, but due to limitations within EE it is pretty difficult to use either format as image sources within your site - EE's "File Manager" system does not currently recognise either format.

A better question to ask yourself though is why you would want to output images in either format in the first place: [webp is not supported by macOS Safari yet, and only by the most recent version of iOS](https://caniuse.com/webp).  Similarly Jpeg2000 has limited support (e.g. AFAIK it is still not supported on Firefox).  So unless you are targetting a closed group of browsers that you know support the format, you'd need to provide an alternative image format in a more compatible format anyhow - so might as well just provide the compatible alternative...

HTH